# Explanation for custom htaccess line added to old Wordpress multisite install

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, multisite

The following custom htaccess line was added to a wordpress old multisite install. I was wondering if anyone can explain what it is doing.

```
# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]
```

Original below:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

the file wp-includes/ms-files.php is the upload handler for multisites.

before WP Version 3 this was the method to handle upload, after version 3+ you don't need it anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I upgraded to the latest WP multisite version. If I remove that line from the htaccess file my images that I upload to the media library will not show. That is the media libraries for all the subdomains. I put the line back in and it is fine.